# How to remove or disable a SharePoint email notification in Microsoft 365

Tags: sharepoint

I created an email notification in SharePoint 365 recently for changes to a library or folder, and I get emails constantly when files are added in any folder or subfolder. This isn't what I intended, so I want to remove the notification, but I can't find it anywhere. How can I find the SharePoint email notification I created so that I can remove it?

Answer (score 1):

See Microsoft's
[Manage, view, or delete SharePoint alerts](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-view-or-delete-sharepoint-alerts-99dfb19c-9a90-4a8c-aba1-aa8c8afb0de2#ID0EBJ=Modern):

> View and cancel an alert for myself on SharePoint
>
> 1. In the list or library where you've set the alerts, select the ... (ellipses), and then select **Manage My Alerts**.
> 2. In **My Alerts** on this site, next to the alert you want to delete, select the checkbox.
> 3. Select **Delete Selected Alerts**, and then select **OK**.

Comment: I've seen that, but when I open My Alerts on the folder/list I think it should be on, it doesn't show any alerts.  As I asked, how can I find it?

Comment: Did you use another user when creating the alert? In any case, try the method in my link under "View or cancel an alert for another person on SharePoint".

Comment: No, not a different user.  The User Alerts option also doesn't show any alerts.

Comment: Have you used [Microsoft Power Automate](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-US/templates/details/f202f581-4cb5-46e8-83db-99de912eb581/send-me-an-email-when-a-new-file-is-added-in-sharepoint-online/)?

Comment: Aha! That was it, thanks for that.  Forgot I set it up in there because I couldn't find a way to do it inside SharePoint.